# My divs won't align correctly

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've been working on a website and I've ran into a problem.

My divs won't align correctly for events, news and three middle descriptions... Here's the code. (Sorry if it's very messy... I'm working on that right now too.) It won't let me post the code for the EVENTS & NEWS so bear with me.

Three description divs.

```
<div class="mainall">

 <div class="descc1">
 <div class="deschead1"></div>
 <div class="thumb1"></div>
 <div class="head1"></div>
 <div class="headbg1"></div>
 <div class="descsep1"></div>
 <div class="desc1">
     <p></p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="descc2">
 <div class="deschead2"></div>
 <div class="thumb2"></div>
 <div class="head2"></div>
 <div class="headbg2"></div>
 <div class="descsep2"></div>
 <div class="desc2">
     <p></p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="descc3">
 <div class="deschead3"></div>
 <div class="thumb3"></div>
 <div class="head3"></div>
 <div class="headbg3"></div>
 <div class="descsep3"></div>
 <div class="desc3">
     <p></p>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS - http://pastebin.com/HPSikFjM

Mainall =

```
.mainall {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 25px;
 overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: What defines "correctly"

Comment: When you zoom they will look un-aligned. And from what I've heard other people I've tested with told me it looks un-aligned on their resolution.

Comment: Have you looked into floating the "columns"?

Comment: I tried to float it but I couldn't figure out how to do it right. Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to create three text columns next to each other with a header text and thumbnail. First thumbnail, next header image and the header background image and then the text column.

Comment: Added Mainall, forgot that.

Comment: Might be worth looking into a CSS framework, like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ or http://foundation.zurb.com/ - they've done 80% of the work for you to get consistent layouts...

Comment: Will these work with Wordpress? I'm going to run the site I'm making on wordpress.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works perfectly - I tested it on your live site:

**CSS:**

```
.descc1{
margin-right: 2.1275%;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 31.914893617021%;
}

.descc2 {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 31.914893617021%;
margin-right: 2.127659574468%;
}

.descc3 {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 31.914893617021%;
}

.mainbox {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. :) How'd you achieve this?

Comment: @Venzire I built it all through chrome dev tools, that's how I always solve css issues.

Comment: @Venzire fair warning, I'll be going to bed in a few minutes, so if you have questions ask away while you still can :)

Comment: All good, It's working now, if I need anything I'll be sure to ask you. Thanks a ton man I was having heaps of trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see what you are trying to do.  You need to float each of your columns left then add a clear fix to the last element.

```
<div id="outside-div-that-expands-to-full-avaliable-size">
   <div class="third">First</div>
   <div class="third">Second</div>
   <div class="third">Third</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

with the css

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

Is this the effect you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/HPY2X/1/

Comment: Thanks I'll try that in a few minutes, I've got a few things to do before I start working again. ;)